# aspnet core 2.2 web app environment variables not changing in docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've got an ASP.NET core 2.2 web app that I have enabled docker support for.  I have created a test app here for review [here](https://github.com/ossentoo/testdockerwebapp).

I am running it in VS with Docker locally.  I want to add environment variables/secrets to the app settings secrets in order to override the values in the appsettings.json file.  In order to do this locally, I have tried changing values in:

- [launchsettings.json](https://github.com/ossentoo/testdockerwebapp/blob/master/TestWebApp/Properties/launchSettings.json)
- [Dockerfile](https://github.com/ossentoo/testdockerwebapp/blob/master/TestWebApp/Dockerfile)

however, for both of these, when I attach to my docker instance and printenv the variable values,  I find that the variable for ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT still shows up as Development.

I am attaching to the running container like this:

```
docker exec -t -i 4c05 /bin/bash
```

I have searched all files in my solution. I can't find ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT being set to Development anywhere in the solution. However, somehow, the environment variable is still being set with that value.

What could be going wrong?  I want that variable to change.  Once working, what I really want to do is to add a connection string secret to environment variables so that it can be used locally via the appsettings.json file or via a docker secret environment variable if the aspnetcore web app is running in a container.  I think I've got this code working, it's just that the variables are not being deployed as expected to the running container.

My VS version is:
[image: VS version]

thanks

Comment: can you show me how you're looking for the environment variable ?  I see you're running bash, but that doesn't show me what you did to theoretically check for the evnrionment variable.  Your dockerfile definitely sets it (misspelling / typos notwithstanding)

Comment: hi Dan, I am running this: docker exec -t -i 4c83 /bin/bash.  Once connected, I then run printenv.  of course 4c83 is the container id

Comment: I'm just trying it using docker-compose now.  I have added Orchestrator Support to the web project

Comment: your use of env seems correct to me, fwiw.

Comment: I downloaded and ran your code (on a mac) and got the correct env variable printed from `printenv`: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1fsjx5650nt5sfo/Screenshot%202018-12-27%2023.06.32.png?raw=1 - must be something VS is doing?

Comment: thanks Claire.  Strange.  I've also tried the same on VS 2019 Preview 1 and get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmm - seems there is a problem with DockerFile support in VS.  However, when I use the Orchestration Support, using docker-compose, the functionality works as expected, so I'm answering the question myself :-)